# Problems with HTTPS and SharePoint7 although page is easily found with HTTP

Tags: iis-7, https, sharepoint-2007

I have an odd situation with a DEV site at work. Last week, our sys admin was experimenting with moving our DEV servers but didn't get chance to finish the job so rolled back his changes.

When I type in this URL http://mylocalsharepointsite/anypage.aspx then I get the page easily. However, when I change the protocol to https I first get a message warning me about the certificate, then when I click ignore warning I get a 404 error.

I know the site and pages are there because I go to IIS and can see the site, the directory it is mapped to and the SSL certificate, which since it's DEV we generated ourselves.

I suppose my question should be this, what are the things I should look at first, is there anything obvious I've overlooked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was with IIS and the certificates. I re-generated the certificates, even though there didn't seem to be anything wrong with them.

This page helped me a lot, especially the two tools: SelfSSL and SSLDiag.

http://www.iis-aid.com/articles/how_to_guides/creating_self_signed_certificates_iis